# Issue with a python function returning a generator or a normal object

Tags: python, iteration, generator, yield

I defined the function `f` as

```
def f(flag):
    n = 10
    if flag:
        for i in range(n):
            yield i
    else:
        return range(n)
```

But `f` returns a generator no matter what `flag` is:

```
>>> f(True)
<generator object f at 0x0000000003C5EEA0>

>>> f(False)
<generator object f at 0x0000000007AC4828>
```

And if I iterate over the returned object:

```
# prints normally
for i in f(True):
    print(i)

# doesn't print
for i in f(False):
    print(i)
```

It looks like `f(False)` returns a generator which has been iterated over. What's the reason? Thank you.

Comment: If a function has a `yield` in it, even unreachably, it's always a generator.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A function containing a `yield` statement **always** returns a generator object.

Only when you iterate over that generator object will the code in the function be executed. Until that time, no code in the function is executed and Python *cannot know* that you'll just return.

Note that using `return` in a generator function has *different semantics* than in a regular function; `return` in this case simply is seen as 'exit the generator here'; the return value is discarded as a generator can only produce values via `yield` expressions.

It looks like you want to use `yield from` instead:

```
def f(flag):
    n = 10
    if flag:
        for i in range(n):
            yield i
    else:
        yield from range(n)
```

`yield from` requires Python 3.3 or up.

See the [`yield` expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) documentation:

> Using a `yield` expression in a function’s body causes that function to be a generator.
>
> When a generator function is called, it returns an iterator known as a generator. That generator then controls the execution of a generator function. The execution starts when one of the generator’s methods is called. At that time, the execution proceeds to the first `yield` expression, where it is suspended again, returning the value of expression_list to the generator’s caller.

Iteration over a generator calls the [`generator.__next__()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.__next__), triggering execution.

If you wanted to return a generator *some of the time*, then don't use `yield` in this function. You'd produce the generator by other means; using a separate function for example, or by using a generator expression perhaps:

```
def f(flag):
    n = 10
    if flag:
        return (i for i in range(n))
    else:
        return range(n)
```

Now no `yield` is used in `f` and it will no longer produce a generator object directly. Instead, the generator expression `(i for i in range(n))` produces it, but only conditionally.

Answer (score 6):

You can work around this by using a nested function that actually uses `yield`:

```
def f(flag):
    def gen():
        for i in range(n):
            yield i
    n = 10
    if flag:
        return gen()
    else:
        return range(n)

>>> f(True)
<generator object gen at 0x7f62017e3730>
>>> f(False)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

As Martijn points out, any function containing a `yield` will always return a generator object, so if in some cases you want the body of `f` to actually be executed when `f()` is called, rather than only be executed when iterated over, you have to use this approach.

The standard library instance method [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map) from `concurrent.Futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`/`concurrent.Futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` uses this to ensure futures are submitted as soon as `map` is called, rather than only when you try to actually retrieve results from it, for example:

```
def map(self, fn, *iterables, timeout=None):
    if timeout is not None:
        end_time = timeout + time.time()

    fs = [self.submit(fn, *args) for args in zip(*iterables)]

    # Yield must be hidden in closure so that the futures are submitted
    # before the first iterator value is required.
    def result_iterator():
        try:
            for future in fs:
                if timeout is None:
                    yield future.result()
                else:
                    yield future.result(end_time - time.time())
        finally:
            for future in fs:
                future.cancel()
    return result_iterator()
```

Answer (score 0):

The generator doesn't just automatically produce the next yield value, unless you specifically call something like

```
next()
```

on it. I had a generator named "generate parameters", and it worked correctly once I did:

```
print(next(generate_parameters()))
```